# how to get Fully Qualified Name of duplicate fields in pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
File file = new File("E:/kamlesh/PdfBox/field name test.pdf");
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
PDAcroForm form = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
List<PDField> fields = form.getFields();
for (int i=0; i<fields.size(); i++) {
    PDField f = fields.get(i);
    System.out.println(f.getFullyQualifiedName());
}
```

output: its getting once if same field is used in multiple time..

need: if same field qualified name is coming mutiple time then display mutiple time..

Comment: some one given solution here ..
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2148

but getKids()  i got error : The method getKids() is undefined for the type PDField

Comment: if a field is defined multiple times the field definition and as such the fully qualified name exists once. To get the number of occurrences and where these are use `getWidgets()` which will give you the annotations associated with the field. Are you looking for a specific information?

Comment: Please try printFields.java from the source code download, and/or share your PDF.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr :printFields.java where i can downloads?

. issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2148

Comment: @ Maruan Sahyoun  : any working code for getting duplicate name of form field?

Comment: @Maruan Sahyoun : getwidgets ().size() giving no of occurrence of duplicate field.. so how  can  i get co- ordinate of each field?

Comment: @kaml download is here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi#20x  or use this code (for 2.0.6): https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/PrintFields.java?view=markup

Comment: Can you share the file in question for analysis? If you don't get to see all widgets, chances are that there is an issue with the PDF.

Comment: @kamlesh Are you still interested in this issue? If you are, please provide the example document Tilman asked for. If not, please delete the question.