# The method getKids() is undefined for the type PDField

Tags: pdfbox

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2148

When there are multiple copies with the same field name, the `getFullyQualifiedName` for each kid in the list of PDField objects returns the name of the parent, followed by `.null`. So if the parent field is called `Button2` and it has 4 instances the result of printing out all the names will be:

```
Button2.null
Button2.null
Button2.null
Button2.null
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? This just seems like a copy-paste of a bug report.

Comment: how to get Fully Qualified Name of duplicate fields in pdfbox

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2148

Comment: It says the problem was resolved in v2.0.0 - can you upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: IMO this is just an extension of your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816401/d-how-to-get-fully-qualified-name-of-duplicate-fields-in-pdfbox

Comment: i am using latest 2.0.6 jar but still same problem
the link u are sharing is asked by me.

Comment: Could you share a sample PDF using a public location?

Comment: you can get a pdf in above link.https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2148

Answer (score 3):

*According to the comments to the question, the OP refers to PDFBox 2.0.x versions, in particular 2.0.6.*

#### getKids()

> The method `getKids()` is undefined for the type `PDField`

In PDFBox 2.0.6 there are two immediate sub-classes of `PDField`. Different variants of the former (1.8.x) `getKids()` method are implemented in there:

- `PDNonTerminalField` - the method retrieving the kids in this class is `getChildren()` and returns a `List<PDField>`, a list of form fields.
- `PDTerminalField` - the method retrieving the kids in this class is `getWidgets` and returns a `List<PDAnnotationWidget>`, a list of widget annotations.

#### name of the parent, followed by `.null`

> When there are multiple copies with the same field name, the `getFullyQualifiedName` for each kid in the list of `PDField` objects returns the name of the parent, followed by `.null`

This is not the case in PDFBox 2.0.x.

In the sample document attached to the PDFBox issue PDFBOX-2148 PDFBox now correctly finds only a single field which appropriately is named "Button2". This field is a `PDTerminalField` and has 4 widget annotations. The class of the latter, `PDAnnotationWidget`, has no `getFullyQualifiedName` method, so there are no ".null" names.

Thus, this problem is gone.

#### FQN of duplicate fields

(from the OP's comment responding to *"What exactly is your question?"*)

> how to get Fully Qualified Name of duplicate fields in pdfbox

**There are no duplicate fields in (valid) PDFs**, for a given name there is at most a single field which may have multiple widgets. *Widgets do not have individual FQNs*.

Thus, what you call "duplicate fields" in your example document actually is a *single* field with *multiple widgets*; the name of that field is "Button2" and can be retrieved using `getFullyQualifiedName()`.

#### which page which form field

(from the OP's comments to this answer)

> but how to get current page no in pdfbox.. for example there are 3 page and in page 2 there is a form field so how can i get which page which form field ?

All `PDAnnotation` classes, among them `PDAnnotationWidget`, have a `getPage()` method returning a `PDPage` instance.

BUT: As specified in ISO 32000-1, annotations (in particular form field widgets) are not required to have a link to the page on which they are drawn (except for *screen annotations associated with rendition actions*).

Thus, the above mentioned method `getPage()` may return `null` (probably more often than not).

So to determine the respective pages of your widgets, you have to approach the problem the other way around: Iterate over all pages and look for the annotation widgets in the respective annotation array.

For PDFBox 1.8.x you can find example code [in this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22132921/1729265). With the information given in the previous parts of this answer it should be easy to port the code to PDFBox 2.0.x.

#### checkbox and radio button

(also from the OP's comments to this answer)

> one more issue if i am using checkbox and radio button both then field.getFieldType() output is Btn for both. how to identify it?

You can identify them by inspecting the field flags which you retrieve via `fields.getFieldFlags()`:

- If the **Pushbutton** flag is set (`PDButton.FLAG_PUSHBUTTON`), the field is a regular *push button*.
- Otherwise, if the **Radio** flag is set (`FLAG_RADIO`), the field is a *radio button*.
- Otherwise, the field is a *check box*.

Alternatively you can check the class of the `field` object which for **Btn** may be `PDPushButton`, `PDRadioButton`, or `PDCheckBox`.

Beware: If a check box field has multiple widgets with differently named *on* states, **this check box field and its widgets *act like a radio button group*!** And not only in theory, I've seen PDFs with such check box fields in the wild.

To really be sure concerning the *behavior* of the fields, you therefore also should compare the names of the *on* states of all the widgets of a given check box.

Comment: perfect solution.. but how to get current page no in pdfbox.. for example there are 3 page and in page 2 there is a form field so how can i get which page which form field ?

one more issue if i am using checkbox and radio button both then field.getFieldType()  output is Btn for both. how to identify it?

Comment: `doc.getPages().indexOf(page)` which page being a PDPage object that you got from `widget.getPage()`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr `widget.getPage()` returns the page referenced in the **P** entry of the widget annotation, and this entry is optional. If there is a value, great, use it! But first check if there is. (That been said, there also are documents out there with widgets which point to a single page but which are referenced from the annotation arrays of multiple other pages, too; not exactly valid but encountered often enough.)

Comment: @mkl : I have created pdf and created two 1.textview 2. textview textfield with same fieldname,
but when I parse pdf file and evaluate I got response "TEXT1 and textview"
I searched alot but couldn't fix this issue. please help me.

Comment: please make this a question in its own right (instead of a comment here) and share your document.