# Migration to PDFBox 2.0.x From 1.8.x

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm currently migrating our PDFBox dependency from 1.8.x to 2.0.x.

I encountered several errors:

```
Error:(22, 50) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PDRadioCollection
  location: package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form
```

```
Error:(23, 50) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PDTextbox
  location: package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form
```

```
Error:(241, 30) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getKids()
  location: variable field of type org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField
```

What are the equivalents for these? I'd like to have the same functionalities without breaking the code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I refer to the Java Docs for Apache 2.0.1 PDFBox.

https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/package-summary.html

This contains the summary of classes present for reference.

[image]

Comment: I understand. However, they are not really explicit with which classes are their equivalent 1.8.x counterparts. Can you clarify on this? Thanks.

Comment: @ggg Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44817793/the-method-getkids-is-undefined-for-the-type-pdfield

Answer (score 1):

PDRadioCollection => PDRadioButton

PDTextbox => PDTextField

getKids() => getChildren(), but only for non terminal fields. For terminal fields use getWidgets().

Terminal fields are "real" fields, i.e. where you can write stuff into. They are the leaves of a tree. Non terminal fields have children, which may or may not be terminal fields. The best would be you look at a few PDF files with PDFDebugger, in the acroform segment. Widgets define the appearance of a field. A field can have several widgets, this is useful e.g. if you want to have your name appear on each page of a form but enter it only once.

Comment: what is the difference between PDNonTerminalField and PDTerminalField? I read the documentation but I still could not understand. Can you please explain to me like I'm a 5 y.o.? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't consider myself able to do parenting and I don't have children. Terminal fields are "real" fields, i.e. where you can write stuff into. They are the leaves of a tree. Non terminal fields have children, which may or may not be terminal fields. The best would be you look at a few PDF files with PDFDebugger, in the acroform segment.

Comment: In the PDF specification there is this text: A field that has children that are fields is called a non-terminal field. A field that does not have children that are fields is called a terminal field. A terminal field may have children that are widget annotations that define its appearance on the page. As a convenience, when a field has only a single associated widget annotation, the contents of the field dictionary and the annotation dictionary.

Comment: Is PDRadioButton a direct replacement for PDRadioCollection? Do I need to create a radio button group?

Comment: Thanks in advance. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I can't answer this because I don't know what you are doing. My impression about PDRadioCollection is that it contains both terminal and non terminal fields, but PDRadioButton is just the terminal field. If you want to create radio buttons, see the example in the source code download, CreateRadioButtons.java.